# How do I know if an image is "Premultiplied Alpha"?

Tags: image, opengl, image-processing, opencv, png

I heard that only premultiplied alpha is needed when doing layer blending etc. How do I know if my original image is premultiplied alpha?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't.

The only thing that you can check is if it's not premultiplied. To do it go over all the pixels and see if there is a color-value that has a higher value than the alpha would permit `if(max(col.r,col.g,col.b) > 255*alpha)//not premul`. Any other cases are ambiguous and could or could not be premultiplied. Your best guess is probably to assume that they aren't as that's the case for most PNGs.

Edit: actually, not even the code that I posted would work as there are a lot of PNGs out there with white matte, so the image would have to include parts that have an alpha of `0` to determine the matte color first.

Comment: Actually *all* PNGs are not premultiplied. Source: section 12.8, http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Rationale.html

Comment: @MarkRansom unfortunately not all tools conform to this spec.

Comment: @clamp then those tools have bugs if they are generating PNG output. The spec says PNG files must *not* have premultiplied alpha.

Comment: All PNG images with an alpha channel created by Xcode and included in iOS apps use premult pixel values.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Actually it's a bug in the PNG spec.

Comment: @PeterT: That test still doesn't guarantee that it's not premultiplied. It could be premultiplied with an additive region. Also when you premultiply you do it in linear and then store it in 8-bit sRGB with linear alpha (that's the format expected by GPU sRGB hardware), so for that test to work for non-additive images you should convert to linear first.

Comment: @MarkRansom: the fact that many tools deliberately violate the spec means that the spec does not serve its purpose—i.e. it has a bug and it has to be fixed. Also their 'rationale' for straight-alpha doesn't hold water. You can't encode premultiplied `80808000` RGBA in straight-alpha, so it's neither 'lossless' nor 'more general'. Considering that PNG is a compressed format, it would be smarter to use premultiplied alpha which interplays better with compression. That being said I admit that it's unfair to judge them after 20 years of technology advances. [See also](http://stannum.co.il/blog/6).

Comment: @ybungalobill you can't encode premultiplied `80808000` because it's invalid - no channel in a premultiplied color can be greater than the alpha. And if there are utilities that generate or use premultiplied alpha, there must be another spec that allows other programs to know the difference between the two. All I'd like to know is, where's that spec.

Comment: @MarkRansom: You are wrong. `80808000` is a valid meaningful value in premultiplied RGBA, it represents an additive pixel, and that's the point of saying that premultiplied is **more general** than straight. Software that uses such conventions in PNG usually does it internally by conventions, nobody said that such PNGs have to be interoperable, so you won't see a spec. Though it might be that some of them write some proprietary metadata chunks to signify that.

Comment: @ybungalobill if you could provide me with a link where I could educate myself on the uses of such a color, I'd appreciate it. It certainly isn't covered by Porter-Duff!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130413/discussion-between-ybungalobill-and-mark-ransom).

Comment: The canonical source of truth: https://github.com/LuaDist/libpng/blob/master/png.h#L1170-L1223

Comment: The color channels are typically gamma-encoded but alpha is usually stored linearly (and PNG spec says alpha must be linear).  Comparing the alpha to the max(R, G, B) is a decent heuristic, but it's not actually comparing apples-to-apples.

Answer (score 4):

Android `Bitmap` stores images loaded from PNG with premultiplied alpha. You can't get non-premultiplied original colours from it in usual way.

In order to load images without *RGB* channels being premultiplied I have to use 3rd party `PNGDecoder` from here: http://twl.l33tlabs.org/#downloads

Comment: Since API 19, you now can get non-premultiplied colors from it using [Bitmap#setPremultiplied](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#setPremultiplied(boolean))